# Capping an Aerospike map in Lua

Tags: dictionary, lua, aerospike, aerospike-ce

We want to remove elements from Map bin based on size. There will be multiple threads which will try to do above operation. So writing an UDF to do this operation will make it synchronized between threads. But remove_by_rank_range is not working inside lua. Below is the error iwe are getting:
attempt to call field 'remove_by_rank_range' (a nil value)

sample lua code:

```
 function delete(rec)
   local testBinMap = rec.testBin
   map.remove_by_rank_range(testBinMap, 0, 5)
 end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Lua map API](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/udf/api/map.html) does not include most of the operations of the [Map](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/cdt-map.html) data type, as implemented in the clients (for example, the Java client's [MapOperation](https://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/com/aerospike/client/cdt/MapOperation.html) class).

The performance of the native map operations is significantly higher, so why would you use a UDF here, instead of calling `remove_by_rank_range` from the client?

The next thing to be aware of is that any write operation, whether it's a UDF or a client calling the map `remove_by_rank_range` method, first grabs a lock on the record. I answered another stackoverflow question about this [request flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44075490/aerospike-design-request-flow-internals-resources/44338136#44338136). Your UDF doesn't give any advantage to the problem you described over the client map operation.

If you want to cap the size of your map you should be doing it at the very same time you're adding new elements to the map. The two operations would be wrapped together with `operate()` - an insert, followed by the remove. I have an [example](https://github.com/rbotzer/aerospike-cdt-examples/blob/master/capped_events.py#L120-L134) of how to do this in [rbotzer/aerospike-cdt-examples](https://github.com/rbotzer/aerospike-cdt-examples#capped-collection-of-events).